# Why is destructor hanging

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Below code was working fine. However, when I enable `p=&b` in `GetValue`, the code failed "Debug Assertion Failed". Why?

```
class A{
int *p; 
public: 
A(){p=nullptr;}
~A(){if(p!=nullptr)delete p;}
void GetValue(int b);
};

void A::GetValue(int b){
*p=b;
//p=&b;  this will cause destructor to hang, why?
}

int main(void){
A B;
B.GetValue(5);
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't look fine either way. You can't dereference nullptr and you can't delete memory you didn't allocate.

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer that has been initialized to `nullptr` is cause for undefined behavior. Don't expect any predictable behavior.

Comment: Also, the variable `b` in the `GetValue` function is a *local* variable, an as such its lifetime will end as it go out of scope once the function returns. The variable will, in essence, cease to exist and all stored pointers to it will become invalid.

Comment: Furthermore, your function `GetValue` doesn't really *get a value*. What is the purpose of the function? What is it supposed to do? Is it supposed to ***set*** a value? Then perhaps `p` should *not* be a pointer? If `p` is a value (i.e. a plain `int p;`) then you could just do `p = b` to set the value of `p`.

Comment: Your destructor isn't hanging, your program is crashing.

Comment: A funny side fact: In `A::~A()`, the `if (p != nullptr)` is unnecessary. In cppreference [delete expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete): _its value must be either null or pointer to a non-array object created by a new-expression_ So, `delete p;` when `p` has a `nullptr` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is important that you only `delete` memory that was allocated using `new`. Currently, your class `A` stores a pointer `p` that isn't allocated using `new`, but you do `delete p` as if it had been. The result of this is undefined behavior, which means that your program is not guaranteed behave correctly, and very weird bugs should be expected.

Secondly, in the function `A::GetValue(int b);`, the parameter `b` is a *temporary* variable. When `GetValue` is called, some space is made on the call stack to pass `b`'s value, where it resides for the lifetime of the function. But after `GetValue` returns, `b` *no longer exists* there. While C++ allows you to store pointers to invalidated memory, you need to be careful to avoid using such a pointer.

To make your class `A` work correctly takes a fair bit of touching up, but I'll try to explain as I go. While currently it doesn't seem to make much sense to store an `int*` pointer where a simple `int` member would do, I'll keep using the pointer to help your understanding, and let the managing of a raw pointer be a learning exercise.

---

Most of the problems stem from `A::GetValue(int)`. Here, you're storing the address of a temporary variable, and in a context where a `new`-ed pointer is expected. You should instead make sure to correctly allocate memory, and not store a pointer to the transient parameter `b`:

```
A::GetValue(int b){
    if (p == nullptr){
        // if p is null, it needs to be allocated before being written to
        p = new int(b); // initialize the memory at p to have value b
    } else {
        // otherwise, p has already been allocated, and its old value can be overwritten
        *p = b;
    }
}
```

Another more subtle problem arises when you write the following code:

```
A a1, a2;
a1.GetValue(13);
a2 = a1;
```

What will happen after these lines is that the `p` member of `a1` will be deleted twice, causing yet more undefined behavior. The culprit is the [automatically generated copy assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions), which simply copies `p` from `a1` to `a2` by value. To fix it, you need to write your own copy assignment operator and copy constructor as follows. The copy constructor is a little complex because there are lots of different cases to be handled.

```
class A {
    ...
    A(const A& other) : p(nullptr) {
        if (other.p){
            p = new int(*other.p); // allocate new int and initialize with other's value
        }
    }
    A& operator=(const A& other){
        if (p){
            // if this is managing a pointer
            if (other.p){
                // if other is managing a pointer too, just copy value
                *p = *other.p;
            } else {
                // otherwise, since other is null, delete and make this null
                delete p;
                p = nullptr;
            }
        } else {
            // if this is not managing a pointer
            if (other.p){
                // other is managing a pointer, time to allocate
                p = new int(*other.p);
            }
            // nothing needs to be done if both are null
        }
    }
```

The importance of doing this is explained in the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programmin)).

Comment: when a class contain pointers, do I need to initialize the pointer in constructor ( A(){p=new int;} and member function ( GetValue(){ p=new int;} also? My earlier understanding was to initialize one time.                                                                                                            do I need to write "copy constructor" if I do not use it later on?

Comment: Whatever the case, you should always initialize a pointer before using it. Whether you want to initialize it as `nullptr` or `new int` is up to you. I answered assuming that `p` is allowed to be null, but if it always points to a valid `int`, it greatly simplifies a lot of the logic (and you could/should use a plain `int` instead of a pointer). If you know you won't ever use the copy constructor and assignment operator, declare them deleted as `A(const A&) = delete;` and `A& operator=(const A&) = delete;` to prevent the automatically generated ones from breaking your program logic.

Comment: Hi Alter,  thank you so much for comments. I feel clearer now on understanding the class that involves pointers.

Comment: there is "error C2059 syntax error : ";"  when I type "A(const A&)=delete;" I use VC 2012. is "A(const A&)=delete;" for newer VC version?

Comment: Yes, VS2012 supports very little C++11 features. I would recommend switching to VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short, your code has **undefined behaviour**, so everything can happen. The undefined behaviour starts here:

```
void A::GetValue(int b){
  *p=b;
  //p=&b;  this will cause destructor to hang, why?
}
```

`p` is `nullptr` when the function is called, so `*p` is undefined behaviour. The rest of your code doesn't even matter. And that's the end of the story.

Sorry to be so blunt, but your use of pointers is so completely and utterly wrong that we cannot even know for sure what the intended behaviour of the code really is. Don't use pointers if you don't need to. Don't use dynamically allocated memory if you don't need to. If you need to, use `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::unique_ptr` or other standard classes which hide the pointers from you, so that you don't have to write your own destructors. Avoid direct use of `new` and `delete`.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I should not use "nullptr" to initialize it. I am learning to write a module that its platform involves pointers, dynamic memory. so I like to learn this. The code may not make sense for you but the error confused me