# why must use '*p=a', and use 'p=&a' does not work in constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am a newbie. like to understand why "p=&a" does not work. thank you.

```
  class A{
      int *p;
  public:
      A(int a){p=new int; p=&a;}
      ~A(){delete p;}
  };


  int main(void){
      A B(11);
  }
```

Comment: 1) Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of coding randomly. 2) Do you understand what `&` (address-of operator), and `*` (indirection operator) does, and how does the behavior of those differ? 3) What is the meaning of creating a pointer to a local variable (which is destroyed at the end of scope), while, at the same time, overwriting the pointer you got from `new`, effectively, creating a memory leak?

Comment: Because `a` is the constructor's argument. It is gone after the end of the constructor, the memory the pointer then points to will be junk (and `delete` will probably cause a crash)

Comment: For same reasons stated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306425/why-is-destructor-hanging

Comment: Depends what you mean by "does not work".   The `p = &a` assigns `p` to be equal to the address of `a`.   That has the effect of losing track of (aka leaking) the memory allocated with `new int`.    Then the destructor does `delete p` where `p` points at something not created with operator `new`.   The behaviour is then undefined.

Comment: @hlt "_and `delete` will probably cause a crash_" `delete`ing a pointer, that was not allocated with `new` is undefined behavior. One can, just as likely, not witness any side-effects, as one could witness a crash.

Comment: Memory leak.  You assign `p` to `new` memory, then you overwrite the value in the pointer to point to a temporary variable.

Comment: As a newbie, I recommend doing whatever you can to avoid pointers.  Prefer passing by reference, using `std::string` and `std::vector`, and the *smart pointers*.  Use pointers as a last result (until you learn *everything* about them and create checklists to verify you haven't misused them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A(int a){p=new int; p=&a;}` first of all allocates an `int` to the pointer `p`, then secondly trashes that pointer value with the address of the *temporary* `a`.

So you end up with a *dangling pointer* **and** a *memory leak*! The behaviour of your destructor will be *undefined*.

`*p = a` is fine, since you are *dereferencing* `p`. Although that said, using bare pointers as class members causes problems with copying instances of your object. It's best avoided.

Comment: the error (or crash) was caused by two different memory addresses between created by "new int" and "&a".  if assigned a value to p (*p=a), its newly allocated address was unchanged. so "delete" and "new" address was matched.